# For-loop skipping a term when searching for list of substrings within a list of strings

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, substring

I need to remove from `my_list` anything that contains any substring from `banned` (both lists are very long, approximately 30k+).

Here's a mini example:

```
my_list = ['dnb','distinctive_group_inc','real-estate-profile','estate.com']
banned = ['distinctive','estate']
```

Desired outcome:

```
my_list = ['dnb']
```

I'd like to be able to do it in one go so I tried:

```
my_list = [i for i in banned if i not in my_list]
```

Since that didn't work at all, I tried it in two steps:

```
for i in reversed(my_list):
    for j in banned:
        if j in i:
            my_list.remove(i)
        else:
            pass
```

How can I do it in one step?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you like list comprehension (and I do), then you were on the right track. This takes your starting comprehension but changes the criteria slightly to to exclude words that have any partial match in the banned list.

```
my_list = ['dnb','distinctive_group_inc','real-estate-profile','estate.com']
banned = ['distinctive','estate']

my_new_list = [
    word for word in my_list
    if not any(banned_word in word for banned_word in banned)
]

print(my_new_list)
```

Should result in:

```
['dnb']
```